# Unity error: Invalid layer id. Please use the unique id of the layer (which is not the same as its index in the list)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've 2D project on Unity (2017.1.3)

When gameObject visible is true, it's given error like this in succession

it stopped when I make visible false

Please assist on me What should I do?

```
Invalid layer id. Please use the unique id of the layer (which is not the same as its index in the list).
UnityEngine.Renderer:set_sortingLayerID(Int32)
Anima2D.SpriteMeshInstance:OnWillRenderObject() (at Assets/Anima2D/Scripts/SpriteMeshInstance.cs:419)
```

Comment: Somewhere in your project you are assigning an invalid layer id to this object.. Find that code :)

Comment: there is no code related to that object in my code.

Comment: The issue i coming from the **Anima2D** plugin you're using. In the `SpriteMeshInstance.cs` script and where it is doing this `cachedRenderer.sortingLayerID = sortingLayerID;`. There is really not much you can do since you didn't write that code. Contact the publisher and report the error.